Quantum Espresso aborted with "1 process returned a non-zero exit code."
My workload is not intensive. I have computed more complex systems using Quantum Espresso. However, I am currently take this error.
"The primary job terminated normally, but one process returned a non-zero exit code. As per user direction, the job has been aborted. The 'mpirun' noticed that the process with rank 2 and PID 0 on the node HUAWEI exited on signal 9 (Killed)."
I attempted to resolve the issue by reducing the number of cores, but that did not solve my problem. Could you please help me?
I increased number of cores from 16 to 8.

signal 9 generally means the process was killed by the oom-killer. run dmesg to confirm that.

I added a wslconfig file and allowed my sistem to use all memory. I guess I found my solution.
